# $.ajax() get body only

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have script like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Testing Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="test" href="getthis.php">click here</a>
<div class="get"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.test').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var a = $('body');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getthis.php",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data){            
                $('.get').append(data.find);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

with this script i try to get content getthis.php

getthis.php contains only this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Olalalalala bebe
    </body>
    </html>
```

when i do this i get result the full html of the getthis.php

how i can to only get body content?
which is mean only.
"Olalalalala bebe"

can somebody give me explanation?

Thanks...

Comment: why dont you remove all the html tags and leave the 'Olalalalala bebe'?

Comment: @Tim: because the website is there is a version which with Ajax, and the other without AJAX, with mean this page need HTML tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use http://api.jquery.com/load/ you can load specific page fragments

Comment: +1 I could say this is the best approach based on the Op's problem

Comment: $(".get").load("getthis.php" body); but if your response gethis.php page has a body tg with id ="thisbody" then the code will be $(".get").load("getthis.php" #thisbody);

Comment: After testing your suggest, i prefer this answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for the body tag because some browsers strip it when using load();

Answer (score 6):

Pretty easy. Wrap inner of BODY by one more layer of DIV will do:

```
$.get(url, {}, function(data){
  var data = data.replace('<body', '<body><div id="body"').replace('</body>','</div></body>');
  var body = $(data).filter('#body');
  //... do what you want with body ...
});
```

Comment: Well this does what I need, but it's not exactly pretty and probably very slow if the page you are loading is big (two .replace creates two new strings).

Comment: Probably an approach using indexOf("<body") and substr would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Wondering if this helps:

```
$(data).text();
```

This seems to work out of the box:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861325/ajax-get-body-only/',
    success: function (data) {
        alert($(data).text().replace(/\s+/gm, ' '));
    }
});
```

Comment: i get this in console.log "(an empty string)"

Comment: I've updated the post, now it seems to work in console. (PS: to run the example in console, you must run this from a browser window that is displaying a page from http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$('.get').load('/getthis.php body');
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I just tested this and it doesn't seem to work using `body` as a selector, which surprises me. If I change `getthis.php` to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
        Olalalalala bebe
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And call it like this:

```
$('.get').load('/getthis.php #test');
```

I get the result you are looking for. But it seems `body` is not a valid selector in this case.

Comment: yes you right. it's seems it didn't support body. i try with ID and Class it's work. thanks you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. And if anybody knows why this doesn't work with `body` as the selector, please comment and let us know!

Comment: jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser. From http://api.jquery.com/load

Answer (score 0):

If not required you exclude html tags from your getthis.php have that data which you want to display on page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some.html",
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#here').html(data);
        $('#here').children('meta,link,title,style').remove();
    },
});
```

Comment: also <script> tag remove